# JavaScript clock works on one page, but not on any others

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a JavaScript clock that is placed in the footer of a page, this particular clock is being used because it displays time up to the second.

The index page contains the script in the `<head>` section, like so:

```
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
```

And the `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
```

In the footer, a `<span>` is in place for the clock:

```
<span id="clock"></span>
```

And it all works fine, the seconds count away, hours and minutes change accordingly.

This index page contains all header and footer code within itself. There is an entrance form button that needs to be clicked to enter the rest of the site and a PHP session is in place to prevent accessing the rest of the site if the enter button isn't clicked.

All the rest of the pages in the site use includes files for the header code. When the code for the clock is inserted in the `<head>` section in the header includes file - in exactly the same place in the `<head>` section as it is in the index page - the clock loads and displays the time, but the seconds do not count in real time, and equally, the minutes do not update when they should, the clock only displays the time that the page loaded.

I checked the console and I'm receiving these errors:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
startTime        https://website.com/home:144:1
onload             https://website.com/home:1:1
```

I have removed the code from the header includes file and moved it to just before the body tag in the footer with no change.

With the script in the EXACT same place in the includes file `<head>` as it appears in the index page's `<head>` the clock does not work beyond displaying the time the page loaded.

How can this work on one page and not on the next one?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: *In the footer, a <span> is in place for the clock:* `<span id="clock"></span>` but your code ALSO looks for `document.getElementById('clock_640')` ?

Comment: You say all the pages contain same header but what about the same footer? The error is clear that it can't find that ID

Comment: @Xufox that was my goof...fixed the post, thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl The footer is coded directly into each page (for now) and is exactly the same as the index page footer code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. My guess is while you try to narrow down a minimal representation of it you will find the problem